# getElementsByClassName only getting first 100

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to scrape Yahoo historic share prices. The page shows a year's worth of data but my code returns only the first hundred matches.

The code snippet below gives x a value of 100.

```vb
Dim matches as object
dim html as HTMLDocument

html.body.innerHTML = response`  (previous code has gone to the website and filled response)
Set matches = html.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)")
x = matches.Length
```

Looping through the line of code below, incrementing p, returns the first 100 dates as expected, and works for values greater than 100 on other sites.

```vb
nextdate= html.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px) Pstart(10px)").Item(p).innerText
```

Inspecting the web page I see that the line which should be the next date (the 101st), I want has "==$0" in grey at the end thus:

```
<td class="Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)">==$0
<span>25 Nov 2020</span></td>
```

I assume this is my problem.
Googling suggests it is "the selected DOM Node id" and part of Chrome's development tools so it shouldn't appear in, or affect, my scripts.

Screen grab of inspection
[image]

```vb
'Declarations
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim ISIN As String
Dim website As String

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Range("A14:I365").Clear
    ISIN = Cells(1, 1)
    website = "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & ISIN & ".L/history?p=" & ISIN & ".L"

    Call Get_Web_Page(website, html)
    Call DecodeYahoo(html, 15, 1)
End Sub


Sub Get_Web_Page(website As String, html As HTMLDocument)
'Querys website and returns html object loaded with response
' TeachExcel.com
    Dim request As Object
    Dim response As String

  ' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    request.Open "GET", website, False
    request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    request.send
    response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    html.body.innerHTML = response
End sub


Sub DecodeYahoo(html As HTMLDocument, Rstart As Integer, Cstart As Integer)
    Dim content As String
    Dim DT As Date
    Dim d As String
    Dim matches As Object

    For K = 0 To 400
        Set matches = html.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)") 
        x = matches.Length

        'Last two lines normally replaced with decoding code,
        ' these two used to confirm that there are only 100 results.

        'here follows code to load retrieved data onto Excel sheet.
    next K
end sub
```

Tim I see what you mean, although with a fast internet connection it wasn't obvious. How can I stimulate a second dose?

Comment: How is the `html` variable filled with content? Please provide a [mcve] of your issue that is reproducable for us.

Comment: Please post your whole VBA code and the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you scroll one of the history pages in a browser, it's clear that the content is being "lazy loaded" and added to the page as you scroll down (watch the scrollbar), so 100 items may be the limit of what's initially delivered.